# Pandas: How to apply operation on subdataframe splitted on a column value

Tags: python, pandas

I have maintenance data (from csv file or other sources), the data are formatted as such:

```
Date        Equipment_id    sensor_reading  failure
2017-01-01  eq_1                 1.0        0
2017-01-03  eq_1                 0.5        0
2017-01-04  eq_1                 1.5        1
2017-01-01  eq_2                 Nan        Nan
2017-01-02  eq_2                 0.3        0
2017-01-03  eq_2                 1.0        0
```

I want to apply transformation like interpolation or rolling windows on those data, and I can do this with pandas. But if I use df.interpolate() for example it will interpolate even if the data are from different equipment_id.
There is probably ways to avoid that, but it seems complicated and I can miss errors.

I consider using a for loop to split the dataframe like that:

```
data_dict = {}
for equipment_id in df[Equipment_id].unique():
    data_dict[equipment_id] = df.loc[df['Equipment_id']==equipment_id]
```

And then use operation like df.interpolate() or df.rolling(window_size).min() on each subdataframe before transforming then to numpy array and concatenate them to form my train set.

But I don't really know if what is happening behind the scene. So I was wondering if making those subdataframe to work on separately would cause memory issue or make longer calculations.
I also don't know if there is a cleaner or more canonical way to do that.

Comment: You're trying to reimplement `groupby`: `for equipment_id, sub_df in df.groupby('Equipment_id'): ...`

Comment: Group by doesn't seem to be enough, I tried 
     `df = df.groupby(equipment_id_col_name).resample('D').mean()`
     `for colum_name in column_to_interpolate:`
          `df[colum_name].interpolate()`
So it should add missing day fill with Nan with .resample
But then when I use .interpolate, if first row of new_equipment id, it interpolate with mean between last row of previous equipment id and the next row of current eq_id

Comment: You should probably ask a new question relating to the real objective. Provide example data and the expected output.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want to apply a rolling window/function on each id individually. In that case, groupby() and apply() will help.

For example, this will apply a rolling window for each id that calculates the sum of a 3 row window:

```
df.groupby(equipment_id).rolling(3).sum()
```

if you would like to interpolate (note how you dont need to pass in an argument):

```
df.groupby(equipment_id).apply(pd.interpolate)
```

and you can also mix those:

```
df.groupby(equipment_id).rolling(3).apply(pd.interpolate)
```

Comment: I tried using your method, pd.interpolate doesn't seems to exist, but I did what I wanted using apply as you said `df = df.groupby('equipment_id').apply(lambda group: group.resample('D').mean().interpolate(method='index'))`.
May be you can modify your answer so I validate it